# Custom Titles for Multiple Tag Taxonomy Page

Tags: taxonomy, tags

Let me explain what I want to achieve.

Normally WordPress allows "filtering" tags with multiple tags. It goes like this:

https://example.com/tag/tag1+tag2

It's useful when `tag1` has a lot of posts.

What I want to do is set up custom title and H1 for that page. Unfortunately by basis this page looks exactly as `tag1` page. I don't know how to call second tag in permalink in this case to change the title. Or rather to add words if there is another one.

Another option I came up with would be setting up another tag with name like `tag1-tag2`. And then somehow make it that it only shows posts that include both tags. But I think it sounds simpler than it is.

//
So i tried getting second tag that is filtered with first one
get_the_tags pulls tags from posts, so $tag[2]->name works but it always return second one
How else to do it in this situation to only return second tag when it's queried with first one

Comment: what would that custom title be? Is it user defined? Or are you asking how to detect this situation in PHP code? I removed the request for a plugin as it would have meant closing your question as off-topic, you can't ask for recommendations or make plugin requests here

Comment: User defined custom title would be the best but then i assume it would require separate page/tag (which would also allow easier way to set up page title tags). I thought of making separate taxonomy of combined tags. But overall I would be fine with having it auto generated with H1 being like "Tag1 tagged Tag2".  To do that i need to retrieve the tag from after + in permalink.

Comment: Ok, you should ask for just one of those though, then edit your question to make that clear as not everybody reads the comments